# Prove that $ T $ is at most countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a theorem from Rudin's $ \textit{Principle of Mathematical Analysis} $ which says that if $ \displaystyle \{E_{n}\}, \; n = 1, 2, 3, \dots $ is a sequence of countable sets, then their union $ \displaystyle S = \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \; E_{n} $ is at most countable. I have successfully understood the proof for this theorem. (The notion of a countable set used in Rudin's book is slightly different from the one I find on Wikipedia, please see below for the clarification of the concept.)

Rudin then goes on to this theorem: Let $ A $ be an at most countable set and for every $ \alpha \in A, \; B_{\alpha} $ is at most countable. Prove that $ \displaystyle T = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \; \in \; A} \; B_{\alpha} $ is at most countable. He says that since $ T $ is equivalent to a subset of $ S $ from above, this theorem must be true, but I can't see why it is the case. Specifically, if all the $ B_{\alpha} $s are finite or if they are all countable, then $ T $ is finite or countable and hence $ T $ is at most countable. But what happens when some $ B_{\alpha} $s are finite and some are countable? In addition, I don't see the reason why the set $ A $ must be at most countable?

Any help would be appreciated!

Some definitions used in Rudin's book: Let $ M $ be a set and $ J_{n} $ be the set of all positive integers up to $ n, $ then $ M $ is finite if there is a bijection from $ M $ to $ J_{n} $ for some positive integer $ n, M $ is countable if there is a bijection from $ M $ to $ \mathbb{Z}^{+}, $ and $ M $ is at most countable if $ M $ is finite or countable.

Comment: If for some $\alpha$, $B_\alpha$ is finite, then it is simply a subset of some countable set. For the case A being uncountable, you may try to construct a set with cardinality same as real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Terminology note: most authors use "countable" to mean what Rudin calls "at most countable." I use Rudin's terminology below, for clarity, but I just wanted to point this out to forestall any confusion down the road if you look at other sources.*

Every finite set is contained in a countably infinite set - just take its union with $\mathbb{N}$.

So suppose I have a collection of sets $B_\alpha$ ($\alpha\in A$), where $A$ is countable; and each $B_\alpha$ is either finite or countable.

Let $C_\alpha=B_\alpha\cup\mathbb{N}$. Then each $C_\alpha$ is countable, so $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} C_\alpha$ is countable.

But $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} B_\alpha\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} C_\alpha$ since $B_\alpha\subseteq C_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$, and any subset of a countable set is at most countable.

---

Also, note that even if each $B_\alpha$ is finite, that does *not* mean that their union is finite! E.g. let $A=\mathbb{N}$ and set $B_\alpha=\{\alpha\}$.

---

As to why the index set $A$ needs to be at most countable: otherwise the theorem is false!

If $A$ is uncountable, let $B_\alpha=\{\alpha\}$ for each $\alpha\in A$. Then each $B_\alpha$ is at most countable, but $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}B_\alpha=A$ is uncountable!

Comment: Regarding your last statement, if each $ B_{\alpha} $ is at most countable (so each is either finite or countable), doesn't it mean that the union of all $ B_{\alpha} $s must be countable according to the theorem with $ S = $ union of all countable sets are countable? I know it is contradictory since the union of all $ B_{\alpha} $s is $ A $ and $ A $ is uncountable, but I don't know how to explain this inconsistency.

Comment: @PhucNguyen No - the theorem **requires as a hypothesis** that the index set, $A$, be at most countable. The theorem says: if $B_\alpha$ is at most countable for each $\alpha\in A$, *and $A$ is at most countable*, then $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} B_\alpha$ is at most countable." There is no contradiction.

Comment: Note that when you write "union of all countable sets are countable," you're misstating the theorem. The union of *countably many* countable sets is countable, but an uncountable union of countable sets need not be.